# Is there a tool to learn to pronounce aviation jargon accurately?

Tags: books

So I've been reading technical aviation books and I come across a lot words I want to learn to say correctly but unlike simple words which I just look up in an audio Oxford dictionary I can't think of where online I can find audio pronunciations of aviation words. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind perhaps giving some examples? :)

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot Like...DIHEDRAL.  ☺

Comment: I don't think you will find a specific aviation resource but most words should be in online dictionaries, [for example, dihedral](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dihedral).  Click `Syllables` then the speaker to hear it.

Answer (score 4):

With the exception of abbreviations (like FSDO, pronounced `fizz dough`) there's not much "jargon" in aviation that's not a standard word in whatever language you're speaking. Words like "dihedral", "anhedral", "aileron", etc. should certainly show up in a dictionary.

The abbreviations are "tribal knowledge" the same way they are in any other field (e.g. SCSI, SATA, IMAP in the tech field). I'm not aware of any authoritative compendium of pronunciations.

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't a reference, per se, but you can hear a lot of these words in context a few of ways:

- http://www.liveatc.net - Is one great example.  It will allow you to listen to live ATC, and they'll be saying a lot of the same world you want to hear.
- https://www.pilotedge.net - Along the same lines, but instead it's a plugin for your flight simulator that allows you to interact with actual ATC professionals on a virtual ATC network.  Not only good for listening, but also for learning to use a lot of the words.
- http://www.youtube.com - Okay, this probably didn't need to be listed like this, but it's also useful :).  There are A LOT of videos online for learning aviation, and they probably use many of the words you are curious about.  So I'd try that as well.

Between all these resources it should be pretty easy to get at the "tribal knowledge" voretaq7 referenced in his answer.

Comment: Well, damn, memories are bittersweet. I went to liveatc.net, saw that they had an Android app, downloaded it, and brought up KJFK tower ... and then cried a little. I retired nearly 16 years ago now, but I still severely miss flying. I was based at KJFK for the last 10 years.